# Question on jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have a few questions on jQuery AJAX.

1. It is confusing to understand why there are multiple methods like load(), get(), post()..is the diff only like $.ajax is general way of writing and others being specific based on type..?
2. I do not cleatly understand the diff between complete, success..Are they similar or is there any diff as to when each should be used ?
3. In terms of script execution from within an HTML response, does jQuery AJAX handle it automatically OR do we need to specify something like eval() ? Also how diff is this behavior compared to a normal AJAX only handling?
4. Regarding the beforeSend , is it similar to ajaxSetup and generally speaking, what are the common attributes which are used out of the many which are availbale?

***Edited***

1. Also is the code written as callback for load()..e.g. load(url,function(){});
   same as what is mentioned under success or ajaxSuccess..I mean will the callback function code not exectuted at the same time as the success or ajaxSuccess ?

Thnak you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) you need to understand HTTP.  `get` and `post` make "GET" and "POST" requests, respectively, which is useful if you are building a RESTful service.  EDIT: I actually don't see get and post methods on the ajax object; you pass a 'type' parameter to specify the HTTP method you want to use.

2) `success` fires on success, i.e. if the response returns a 200.  `complete` always fires after everything else is done.

3) Ideally, your server would return json.  If you configure the Ajax call to expect json, then it will parse it for you.

4) The documentation is very clear, `beforeSend` is fired before the actual underlying ajax request is invoked.  The documentation says things like "Use this to set custom headers, etc."

Comment: So for 1, the diff is mostly in terms of syntax and in terms of if we want to make a specific thing like get,post...Also for 4, what is ajaxSetup used for mainly?

Comment: @hmthr as it says here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup setup is to set default values.  So you do ajaxSetup when you app loads to set sensible defaults.  For example, you can set dataType = 'json' so everytime you do an ajax call you don't need to specify it.

Comment: So in a way speaking ajaxSetup is kind of global setting, while beforeSend is specific to that AJAX request ? Is that correct?

Comment: @hmthr yes.  beforeSend allows you to do things like set a loading mask for example.  You would remove the loading mask in the complete callback.  Use @hvgotcodes so I get notified if you reply

Answer (score 0):

1. They are just "shorthand"
   everything can be done and function
   the exact same with $.ajax(), the
   difference is only syntax
2. `complete` is fired after every request is complete, while `success` only fires if there were no errors (a successfully one
3. whatever you want to do with the HTTP response you do by making a function(data){dostuff(data);} in the `success` callback area
4. `beforeSend` is called right before the ajax request is fired

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)